# Finding common keywords in the result documents of a query

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an index in the elsaticsearch that has a field with type of keywords, I want to get the common keywords of the documents from result of a query!
In other words, I want to query the index and find the keywords that are included in all of the result documents, is there any way to do this without fetching all the result documents and calculating the common keywords by ourselves?

**Example:**
Lets assume that we have an index of book data and each book has a keyword field with type of keyword that contains related keywords to that book and each book contains a publisher field, I want find the common keywords in all the book that are published by a specific publisher!

```
{
 title: Title1
 publisher: Publisher1
 keywords: keyword1, keyword2, keyword3
}
{
 title: Title2
 publisher: Publisher1
 keywords: keyword1, keyword4, keyword5
}
{
 title: Title3
 publisher: Publisher1
 keywords: keyword1, keyword2, keyword4
}
{
 title: Title3
 publisher: Publisher2
 keywords: keyword7, keyword8, keyword9
}
```

I have 4 document, and I want to find the common keywords for the books that published by `publisher1`, the result should be `keyword1` in the above example!

Comment: Can you provide an example of what you're trying to achieve?

Comment: I have added an example to the description.

Answer (score 0):

Using a simple `terms` aggregation with size 1 can achieve what you expect. The query below will return the most used keyword for books published by `Publisher1`:

```
POST publishers/_search
{
  "size": 0,
  "query": {
    "match": {
      "publisher": "Publisher1"
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "keywords": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "keywords",
        "size": 1
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
  "aggregations" : {
    "keywords" : {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound" : 0,
      "sum_other_doc_count" : 6,
      "buckets" : [
        {
          "key" : "keyword1",
          "doc_count" : 3
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Comment: The result of this is the most frequent terms, so I cannot be sure that all the documents contains that keywords, also I need to get all the common keywords. There is a way to do that, so I can first execute the query and find the total hit of that query and use that total count for `min_doc_count` of the second query to just find the keywords with minimum document count of all hit documents, but the problem is, based on the elastic docs, this number is not accurate!